# How can I make a VS Code shortcut for select previous/next in the show fixes menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press `ctrl+.` to see fixes I can use `UpArrow/DownArrow` to select, but I can't find any mention of this shortcut in the 'keyboard shortcuts' menu. How can I add `alt+j` and `alt+k` to move the selection up and down? I have managed it for all other areas, but not this! I have this so far:

```
[
  // move cursor
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "cursorUp",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "cursorDown",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+l",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+h",
    "command": "cursorLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+l",
    "command": "cursorWordEndRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+h",
    "command": "cursorWordStartLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  // navigate lists and explorer
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "list.focusUp",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "list.focusDown",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+l",
    "command": "list.expand",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+h",
    "command": "list.collapse",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  // smart select
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+l",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+h",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.shrink",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  // select suggestion
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
]
```